# How Stop Specific setTimeout Loop Using clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, audio, callback, settimeout, cleartimeout

How can I stop a specific `setTimeout` loop using `clearTimeout(myVar)`?

I am using multiple callbacks that include unique audio file names as parameters. When the function `triggerAudio` receives a callback, it starts an audio file loop. The issue is that if I have started more than one setTimeout audio loop (i.e., multiple sounds are playing at the same time), how can I stop a specific loop/sound/setTimout? Said another way, how can I choose which audio loop is stopped?

```
// starts 1.wav looping
(function loopStart() {
    triggerAudio('1.wav');
}());

// starts 2.wav looping
(function loopStart() {
    triggerAudio('2.wav');
}());

// stops one of the audio loops after 5 seconds
setTimeout(function() { 
    (function loopStop() {
        clearTimeout(myVar); // not sure how to control which function this will stop/clear
    }());
}, 5000);

// main functino that loops the files noted by the callbacks 
function triggerAudio(soundFileName) { 
    // code that starts and loops audio file with setTimeout loop
}
```

I suspect I need to somehow name (I'm not sure of the terminology) the `setTimeout` started by each callback so that I can stop that one? But, I'm not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {...}, 1000);
```

then you can call clearTimeout(timeout) to clear your timeout function. For your scenario, you can just use a variable to keep the timeout object, so when you try to play the video, you can validate the timeout object and clear it if it is not undefined, like this:

```
if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout)
```

to stop the previous timeout